# SQL query takes very long

Tags: mysql

I have a table, named **Ads**, which contains ~441.000 rows, and 21 columns.

I am trying to run the following query:

`SELECT Ads.* FROM Ads WHERE Ads.countries_CountryId = 'FR'`

I put an index, to the countries_CountryId field, which is of type `char(2)`, but when I run the above query, it takes around 5-8 seconds to complete. This ammount of time looks immensly high for me, for such a medium sized table, and such a simple SQL query. Where should I look for the problem? Or is it normal for such a query to take so long?

I also tried to `EXPLAIN` the above query, and get the following results, but I don't know how to decipher this:(

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  Ads     ref     countries_CountryId     countries_CountryId     2   const   24368   Using where
```

**EDIT1:** (response to Seth McClaine)

I've tried your suggestion, the way you suggested, returns an error, but if I run `SELECT count(*) FROM Ads WHERE Ads.countries_CountryId = 'FR'`, it runs much much faster: 0.0052490234375

But the problem is, I am not printing out anything, I am using php to run the queries, and calculating their runtime for the moment, and at the end, outputting the queries run, and the time they took:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [query] => SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'
        [duration] => 0.00481009483337
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [query] => SELECT * FROM Countries WHERE NameFormatted LIKE '%FRANCE%'
        [duration] => 0.00234889984131
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [query] => SELECT Ads.* FROM Ads WHERE Ads.countries_CountryId = 'FR'
        [duration] => 4.71820402145
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [query] => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ads WHERE Ads.countries_CountryId = 'FR'
        [duration] => 0.0052490234375
    )
)
```

Here's also the code snippet, that runs the queries:

```
 public function query($query, $cacheit=true) {
    if (!$this->isConnected()) {
        $this->throwError("Querying <b>".$query."</b> failed, because MySQL is not connected!", self::MYSQL_NOT_CONNECTED, false);
        return false;
    }

    $qstart=microtime(true);
    $result=@mysql_query($query, $this->conn_resource);
    $qduration=microtime(true) - $qstart;

    if ($result===FALSE) $this->throwError("Querying <b>".$query."</b> failed!", self::MYSQL_QUERY_ERR);

    $this->numQueries++;
    $this->executedQueries[] = array(
        'query'     =>  $query,
        'duration'  =>  $qduration
    );

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It might not be the query on it's own, there could be several other things that could contribute to a slow output response. For instance, what are the specs of the machine where the DB resides? Are there other concurrent (and possibly process intensive) jobs/processes that are running simultaneously?

Comment: Its look fine, just for testing, use two queries, in ist, select MAX,MIN primary id against this criteria, and than select records between MIN and MAX ids.

Comment: If you are printing out, it may be the actual printing that is taking so long... Try running `SELECT count(Ads.*) FROM Ads WHERE Ads.countries_CountryId = 'FR'` and see if your speed increases significantly

Comment: does this table change frequently? fragmentation may be the thing... Also, do you really need all these 21 columns in this query?

Comment: @SethMcClaine : I've tried your suggestion, the results can be found in the Original Question. Strangely, the count runs lightning fast, but I am not printing out the results anywhere:|

Comment: @miraclefoxx no, the table doesn't change at all at the moment, this is a project that is being built right now, and no one has access to anything from it at the moment.

Comment: Even if you're just showing run-time, you still have transfer all the data for those 21 columns in matching rows. Try selecting just the primary key column.  What is the run time of that?  Something like: `SELECT id FROM Ads WHERE countries_CountryId = 'FR'`?  If it's fast, then your columns' data is likely the problem.

Comment: Does selecting just speicifc columns also speed up the process? (even if you don't print the columns out when the select is run for each field that is gotten back.... it is transferred from teh sql to the webserver and there space is allocated for it........with 21 columns it COULD be (depending on the fields themselves) that that is a time killer....example many big text fields that are quite filled))

Comment: @SethMcClaine it is possible that it isn't even the printing but already the gathering of the data (sending all 21 column fields from the sql to the webserver and allocating space tehre,...) that is slowing down things already (seen that before even without a print). Printing could be adding to  that but not be the only/main problem

Comment: This will be the problem. Selecting a single column speeds it up to below 0.01 seconds. Is there a problem in one of my columns, or the huge ammount of data that slows down the query?

Comment: @AdamBaranyai without knowing the data in your columns from my personal experience it can be just how much data is in the fields. Thus if you have a text field/blob field for example the WHOLE field is transfered when you select it from php. And that COULD be the slowdown. The mainquestion you should ask yourself there thus is do you really need ALL 21 columns and if so, can you restrict the data per field for the sql where you select all the rows

Comment: @Thomas my guess would be look into (google) mysql output buffer and see if that can be a bottle neck/ if you can adjust it

Comment: InnoDB buffer might be something to look at

Comment: @AdamBaranyai removing redundant columns from the select list may improve performance in case you have LOBs. Also, server IO won't change, but it will decrease amount of data you're networking.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried executing the query in read-only mode?
As explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-performance-ro-txn.html) in mysql documentation.
You may try starting your query with

```
START TRANSACTION READ ONLY
```

Also, you may want to try using explain statement to get more information about your query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT Ads.* FROM ....
```

Hope this helps. Helped for me in several large queries.